# Android Native Advance Ad: "Failed to load ad: 0"

Tags: android, admob, native-ads

I followed this Google sample app [NativeAdvancedExample](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/NativeAdvancedExample) and implemented into my app. It was working when I had added test device ID. But when generated released apk, it wasn't working and Ad loading failed with the following message.

```
I/Ads: Starting ad request.
I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("22C0485C025508BC7990BBF9260554DF") to get test ads on this device.
W/Ads: Received error HTTP response code: 403
W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

I have following permissions for the app:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will take time to generate ads for new id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello @ch3tanz native advanced does not load ad , even it does not generate Impression from real device also because it is in Beta Version. So In order to generate Impression you have to implement Native Express Ad.

I have also the same problem like yours.Now I have implemented Native Express Ad. Native Advanced Ad load successfully with test Id but it does not create Impression.

for Express Ad : [This is the link.](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/NativeExpressExample)

Happy Coding

Comment: `Native Express Ad` is deprecated, use `UnifiedNativeAd` instead as per : [Google documents](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/advanced). Please update your answer!